# Como fazer com que o NPM faça atualização sempre do ultimo comite no master?

Tags: git, npm, gitlab

Tenho um repositório local (gitlab) com diversos componentes, estou apontando no `package.json` cada componente diretamente para este repositório. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
"dependencies": {
    "XX-alert": "git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git",
    ...
}
```

Gostaria que toda vez que um desenvolvedor fizesse um `push` para o `master` qualquer um na rede fazendo um `npm update` pudesse pegar esta atualização.

Neste momento para que isso funcione eu preciso adicionar novamente o pacote:

```
npm install git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git --save
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Pode esclarecer melhor, por favor, para quem essa atualização estaria disponível? Outro desenvolvedor? Um ambiente de teste?

Comment: Tenho hoje 40 componentes e todos estão dentro do Gitlab, cada desenvolvedor utiliza o comando `git install git+http://git.domain.com/XX-platform/XX-alert.git --save` para adicionar um pacote ao projeto, a questão é que toda vez que se atualiza o pacote no branch master os desenvolvedores não conseguem ter acesso a essa atualização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você sabe qual a dependência que foi atualizada, você pode rodar o `npm update <pkg>` que ela será atualizada, caso não saiba qual dependência foi atualizada, então sugiro que você remova a pasta do `node_modules` com um `rm -rf node_modules` e rode o `npm install` novamente.

Comment: Lembrando de não deixar o número da versão estática no package.json, senão ele sempre vai instalar aquela versão específica

Answer (score 2):

Bruno, uma boa prática é não versionar isso no Git, quando um dev fizer o clone ele baixa os pacotes e quando atualizar, você tem que colocar esse processo na automação de "build" o Gulp pode te ajudar a automatizar essa tarefas. A única coisa que você versionaria seria o arquivo json com a relação de pacotes, daí é só dar o comando de update do npm, para atualizar os pacotes.